# Prove that $|x| + |y| \le |x-y| + |x+y| $

Tags: inequality, triangle-inequality

I tried working from both sides:

$| |x| + |y|| = | |x| + |x| - |x| + |y|| = | 2|x| + |y| - |x|| \le |2x| + | |y| - |x| |$

$\Longrightarrow||x| + |y|| = |x| + |y| \le |2x| + | |y| - |x| |$

Then,

$|2x| = |x - y + x + y| \le |x-y| + |x+y| $

Can someone help me from this point on?

Comment: Also $|2y|\le|x-y|+|x+y|$.  Now add those two inequalities and divide by $2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that by tringle inequality

$$2|x|=|x+y+x-y|\le |x+y|+|x-y|$$

$$2|y|=|x+y-x+y|\le |x+y|+|x-y|$$

then by addition

$$2|x|+2|y|\le 2|x+y|+2|x-y|$$

Comment: Another clear duplicate ...

Comment: Did you mean $\le$?

Comment: opssss...yes of course! I fix that typo. Thanks

Comment: @MartinR Just a typo of course! Now fixed

Comment: Don't forget to vote to close as a duplicate!

Comment: @MartinR Asker have shown their effort and I wasn't aware of the previous duplicate raised 6 years ago.

Comment: I don't remember all questions from 6 years ago either, but I know how to search! – But now you are aware of it, so you could close-vote *now.* That has nothing to do with the asker's effort: Even good questions can be duplicates.